# Installing SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008

I'm currently trying to assist in the build out of our Company's app on a 64-bit server, as part of "re-upping" our partnership with Microsoft.  To get us to the correct point level, we are trying to install SQL Sever 2008 on Windows Server 2008 R2.  But this isn't possible currently.  [Yes, there is a work around,](http://wadingthrough.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/problem-installing-sql-server-2008-on-windows-2008-r2/) but for reasons I can't begin to speak to, that work around isn't working.  The setupfiles from SP1 are indeed copied to the computer, but when I run the SQL Server 2008 install again, it just gives me the same message about the program having compatability issues, and I am unable to proceed with the install.

Has anyone had any experience with this problem?  Is there another way we can get this up and running?  A work around for the work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out the problem was we had never activated windows.  At least, we activated windows and then the workaround started working around.

Answer (score 0):

The compatibility issues dialog should contain a "Run program" button that you can use to force the installation.

After SQL Sever 2008 is installed, installing SP1 should resolve all compatibility issues.

Also see this Microsoft article :
[Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx)
(do you install SQL Server 2008 **R2**?)

Comment: No, the run program button doesn't do anything when I click it.  Also, this is not SQL Server 2008 R2.  It has to be SQL Server 2008, for reasons beyond my control.

Comment: @peacedog: Sometimes it helps to set the Compatibility mode of the setup file to an earlier Windows version.

Comment: I tried several earlier versions to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

[.NET Framework 3.5 is a prerequisite for SQL Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955725).  It's not installed by default on Windows Server 2008 R2; have you installed it?

Comment: Well, it doesn't show up in programs and features, but it appears to be there (C:\windows\microsoft.net\Framework\x64\ --> 1.1, 2.0, and 3.5 folders present and filled with all sorts of goodness).

I mean, we previously had our company's (.net) app running on the box (it's just that SQL Server 2008 R2 was installed by mistake), so I know .net is alive and kicking.  There's so much different in server 2008, so I'm sure there's a reason I am not seeing it in Programs & Features.

Comment: @peacedog: There is only one reason for not seeing it in Programs & Features - if it's badly installed. I would suggest to re-install it (uninstall if necessary), rebooting at each step.

Comment: @harrymc - it shows up under ServerManager -> Features.  I believe it is installed correctly.  I might try removing it and then re-adding it, though.